# C# in Unity, SetActive several gameObjects from player entering trigger area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Brand new to C# and Unity.Please be nice I've been at this all night. Every tutorial I poor through says changing an object from invisible to visible is as simple as setting the game object to on. However Unity gives me an error when I declare a game object in this script. The objective is, when the trigger is entered, several game objects called 'spawn' will become visible.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class collider : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public gameObject Spawn; // I get error On this line that type is expected, 
                             //not property. It wants a Transform>
    private Rigidbody rb;
    void Start () 
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }



    void OnTriggerEnter(BoxCollider other)
    {


        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Spawn.SetActive(true);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53526483/edit) your question and include the text of the error it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

`gameObject` isn't a type, but `GameObject` is.

Get rid of `public gameObject Spawn;` and use `public GameObject Spawn;` to declare a `GameObject` property called `Spawn`

Comment: Assets/collider.cs(23,10): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a definition for `GameObject' and no extension method `GameObject' of type `UnityEngine.GameObject' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: @Mattonio Okay, what's on line 23? Your question has `Spawn.SetActive(true);` on line 23, but that doesn't match what the error is talking about. You're probably using `Spawn.GameObject.xyz` at some point, when you should be using `Spawn.xyz`.